# Expressions: Variable referenced from scope, but it is not defined exception

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, expression

I'm pretty new in System.Linq.Expresions, and I'm trying to figure out what wrong with this code:

```
 var mc = new MyClass();

        ParameterExpression value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
        ParameterExpression xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "x");

        Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> e = x => x.Val;

        BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(new[] { xParam, value },
            Expression.Assign(e.Body, value));

        Expression.Lambda<Action<MyClass, object>>(block, xParam, value).Compile()(mc, 5); //I'm getting exception here when Compile()

...

class MyClass
    {
        public object Val
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public object OtherVal
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

I'm just want to build something like mc.Val = 5 assuming that MyClass and object parameter is the parameters of lambda (I don't want to use closures)

Comment: People generally appreciate it when you post the full error message and stack trace

Answer (score 9):

`e.Body` references a parameter from `e`. But that is a different parameter than `xParam`. It is not enough that the two have the same names. They must be the same object.

In understand you try to obtain expressions using lambdas as a tool to generate them. For that approach to work you need to replace all parameters in `e` with parameters that you control (`xParam`). You have to be consistent.

Comment: In other words, if you create a lambda expression and then use passed parameters inside that lambda expression (i.e. in a block expression or call expression) - you need to use the same ParameterExpression objects when constructing different expression objects (LambdaExpression and inner expression).

Comment: @nightcoder that is correct. If architecture demands it you can also rewrite an existing expression tree and replace parameter expressions to your liking.